# Using DeBroglie Waves with Compton Scattering

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons

I am presented with the following situation: A light source $\lambda_i$ of unknown wavelength is directed at a carbon sample. An electron is scattered with a speed of $v$ (non relativistic) at an angle $\theta$. Determine the wavelength of the source.

I tried to solve for the kinetic energy of the electron $E_f =\frac{1}{2}mv^2$. However, I have been told to find the associated wavelength of the matter particle via:

$$\lambda_f = \frac{hc}{E_f}$$

Now, I am not sure what to do. Compton formula $\lambda_f - \lambda_i = \frac{h}{mc}(1-\cos(\theta))$ relates the incoming photon with the scattered photon. However, I am not sure if I can use matter waves and the matter deflection angle ... can I do this? If so, what is the justification?

Answer (score 0):

Since the Vector Potential is not unique, you  need to pick a Gauge. For example in Ampere's Gauge we not only require that $\nabla \times \vec{A}=\vec{B}$, but $\nabla \cdot \vec{A}=0. $ In the Lorentz Gauge, we select  $\vec{A}$ so that $\nabla \cdot \vec{A} +\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}=0$ which reduces to the Ampere Gauge in electro statics.

Given the Lorentz Gauge, the Magnetic Vector Potential can be found by $$\vec{A}(\vec{r},t)=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int_\Omega
\frac{\vec{J}(\vec{r}',t')}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|}d^3\vec{r}'$$
For now assume $t=t'=0$.

Mathematically, this vector is a weighted average of the current density. So at a given point in space, the we take an arbitrary portion of $\vec{J}$, the current density, divide it by how far away it is. We add this to the term we get applying the method to other parts of the current density. This gives a vector sum having some net direction.

Note by this analysis, if the current moves in a straight line, then the vector potential is parallel to the current in all space. In a highly symmetric scenario like an infinitely long wire, the magnetic field isn't only the curl of the Vector Potential, it can also be expressed as a constant times the vector cross product of the vector potential with the radial vector to the wire, which is easier to grasp geometrically. The cross product of two parallel vectors is zero, so we see there is naturally a way in which the directions parallel and perpendicular to the current density are special.

A finite wire can be thought of as making the same contribution as the infinite wire with some "correction terms". Further the the weights  mentioned above introduce a For a sufficiently smooth current density not in a straight line, it can be approximated by a series of finite, straight-line curves, each one contributing its own direction to the potential.

As to the $t'$ above, that's the "retarded time". Changes in the field are due to changes in charge and current distributions. Those changes travel at the speed of light. The field isn't due to the current state of charges, but how charges were distributed at some point in the past, hence "retarded time" as opposed to "advanced time".

Current is just moving charge. To a moving charge we can associate a current density by multiplying the charge density by the average of the velocity of the constituent charges at the charges' location. If that velocity is constant, we have a straight-line current density, to which we can apply the earlier analysis, modified a bit to account for scaling effects of relativity.

We have a pure electrostatic field in a frame in which a charge is not moving with no magnetic field. In a frame in which a charge distribution is moving, we have both an electric and a magnetic field. The fields are a sum of multiple charge locations in the past with special treatment for directions parallel and perpendicular to the direction of motion of the constituent charges.

So the direction can get really complicated factoring in considerations of space, time, and the finite propagation speed of effects on the field. Certain symmetries do allow for fairly easy visualizations though.